# How do I use custom Smarty functions in a Form?

Tags: smarty

The "Extending Smarty" page at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extending+Smarty gives instructions for writing custom php functions and calling them from Smarty templates used in Pages, by using the pageRun hook to add a plugin directory to your template.  But this doesn't work for Forms.

For example, a custom function works from the main Case dashboard, but not from the search view when filtering Cases by status.

How do I have the plugin directory included in Forms, not just Pages?

Answer (score 2):

Use the config hook instead of pageRun.  I originally had this hook in place, as per the example at "Extending Smarty":

```
function civicrm_pageRun(&$page) {
  $template = $page->getTemplate(); // retrieve Smarty template object
  array_push($template->plugins_dir, '/path/to/civi_custom/plugins');
}
```

I replaced that with:

```
function civicrm_config( &$config ) {
  $template =& CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton( );
  array_push($template->plugins_dir, '/path/to/civi_custom/plugins');
}
```

and now I can use my custom Smarty functions from both Pages and Forms.

Comment: Yeah, `hook_civicrm_config` makes more sense. I'll do a quick update to the wiki. If you come across another problem like this, consider updating the wiki. ;) Also, a relative path within the module/extension dir might be better -- consider using `__DIR__`.